# Change string format delimeters in python

Tags: python, string, templates

I'd like to template out some config files, but they are not compatible with python's
`"this is a {template}".format(template='string')` formatting

eg.  curly braces are part of the config (nginx config).

Can you change the delimiters to something else?

eg, `'this is a [template]'.format(template='string')`

Comment: AFAIK, it's not impossible to overwrite the format() method.

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35574349/python-format-string-with-custom-delimiters

Comment: **See also:** https://duckduckgo.com/?q=pep292

Answer (score 4):

The solution is to use `string.Template`, and remember to escape all the `$`'s
http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#template-strings